# oracle import joinning 2 tables using query

Tags: oracle, import

Is it possible to join 2 tables inside the query in oracle while importing ? I have a dump for 2 tables tab1 and tab2. and I am trying to query on 1 of the tables:

```
Directory=backup
DUMPFILE=twotables.dmp
logfile=tablesimp.log
tables =  tab1,tab2
Query=tab1:"WHERE code= 2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab2 b WHERE type=b.type and numb=b.numb)"
```

it just give me 0 rows exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `ku$.` do any good? Documentation says that

> The table alias used by Data Pump for the table being loaded is KU$.

```
Query=tab1:"WHERE ku$.code= 2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab2 b WHERE ku$.type=b.type and ku$.numb=b.numb)"
```